# Can I say. ' could you have used a quotation, your article could have looked more professional?'

Tags: grammaticality

I know when constructing a **third conditional sentence**, we need to use the form: **If + past perfect, would/could have + past participle**. In this case, I only used would/could have + past participle in both clauses and I doubted it would give any sense at all.

Comment: Using _could you have_ for _if you could_ is literary and old-fashioned. c.f. "Could I revive within me Her symphony and song..." (Coleridge: Kubla Khan)

Comment: What @Kate says. It's 'grammatical' but the grammar really belongs to a previous time. Certainly, in a sentence containing modern words/usages such as 'article', 'professional', it is ... let's say incorrect ... as the incongruity violates Orwell's Sixth Rule ('Don't say/write anything [approaching the] barbarous'.)

Comment: I'm sorry - what are you trying to ask? Is your quote one sentence or two?